# yii2: make checkbox to be checked

Tags: php, html, yii, active-form

I am using Yii2 framework and I'd like to generate an html code like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="queue-order" name="Queue[order]" value="1" checked>
```

in a view which uses ActiveForm.

I've tried

```
echo $form->field($model, 'order')
          ->checkBox(['label' => ..., 'uncheck' => null, 'checked' => true]);
```

as well as

```
echo $form->field($model, 'order')
          ->checkBox(['label' => ..., 'uncheck' => null, 'checked' => 'checked']);
```

but desired string "checked" does not appear in the generated html code.

Strangely enough, if I substitute "checked" with "selected"

```
echo $form->field($model, 'order')
          ->checkBox(['label' => ..., 'uncheck' => null, 'selected' => true]);
```

then generated html code contains attribute "selected":

```
<input type="checkbox" id="queue-order" name="Queue[order]" value="1" selected>
```

So, how can I generate html code for a checkbox with attribute "checked"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this checkbox will be checked only if `$model->order` property take `true` value and if it has `false` (`0` or `null` or `false` etc) value - field will be unchecked.

Comment: So you mean that Yii always sets status of checkbox  (checked or unchecked) based on the value of the corresponding property? And I can not change the status of the chekbox? Seems strange if I've got it right...

Comment: @Mario You confuse different ways of receiving the item:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#checkbox()-detail and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#checkbox()-detail
 If you use `ActiveForm` then status of checkbox based on the value of the corresponding property of model.

Comment: @Mario if you want to generate input not based on model you should use `Html` helper (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-html.html) : `Html::checkbox( $name, $checked, $options))`

Comment: Thanks, now I've got it. You are right, I should better use Html helper class as you mentioned and not ActiveForm methods to generate the checkbox I need (moreover my checkbox corresponds to a property from an associated table/model). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if your are setting an external value in checkbox.

```
<?php $model->order = "02256"; ?>
<?= $form->field($model, "order")->checkbox(['value' => "02256"]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $form->field($model, 'Status')->checkbox(['uncheck' => 'Disabled', 'value' => 'Active']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use checked attribute to mark it as checked

`<?= $form->field($model, 'agent_email_verification')->checkbox(['checked' => $model->agent_email_verification > 0,  'value' => true]) ?>`